# Java Executable file from JAR

Tags: java

What's a good program to turn a .jar into .exe? I've tried jSmooth, JEXECreator and launchJ to no avail.

Comment: 1) Can you launch the app. as a Jar by double clicking it? 2) Why code in the cross-platform Java then make a Windows native? 3) A good installer for Java rich-client apps. is [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on platforms that support Java.

Comment: 1) No it's Vista. Java Web Start won't work my Vista ...64 bit. I canm however, open it using winzip 2.) Offline version for desktop 3.) yes...

Comment: 1) Can you launch the app. as a Jar by double clicking it? "1) No it's Vista. Java Web Start won't work my Vista ...64 bit." What I said in (1) had nothing to do with JWS. "I can however, open it using winzip"  If WinZip is the *default* program for Jar files, the file association is wrong.

Comment: yes my file association is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the comments:

> *my main class file does not have String (main[]) class... it shouldnb't because it's an applet*

So your JAR does not represent a Java application at all? You need to convert your applet to a Java (Swing) application. Those EXE creators are for Java applications only.

Comment: Erm. My applet is mostly AWT... so it has to be all Swing? bah... thanks.

Comment: AWT is also fine, I just didn't expect that you're still using AWT :) Just supply a main class with a main method which fires the UI, wrap this in an executabele JAR (i.e. doubleclicking it in Windows must execute it) and use the EXE converter.

Comment: Aha, I get what you're saying... mkay. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I prefer JEXECreator 1.9.3, it is very good and easy to use

Comment: Ugh. I got the SAME error using the other two programs as well as using this one. Main Class Def not ofund... http://pastebin.com/dB9Be8xz

Comment: my main class file does not have String (main[]) class... it shouldnb't because it's an applet...

Answer (score 0):

This is commercial but you can try evaluation version of exe4j:
http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html

I have never seen any working free tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html) too, it claims passed the Java Compatibility Test, which makes it equivalent to a regular compiler. I used it once.

But you should know that such solution are somewhat failure prone... I had a hard time trying to compile a rather simple Java app to EXE. In the end, it worked, to some degree.